# What happens when I gain control of a creature that's a different color from my deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I take control of a black creature using a white deck, how do I pay the mana cost to attack if I don't have swamps in my deck? Please help, I'm new to the game.

Comment: You do not need to pay mana to attack (unless a card specifically says you do like Propaganda), and I can't think of one that requires you to pay black mana.

Comment: What white cards are you using to gain control of a black creature?  The only cards I can find are extremely old, nothing recent.

Comment: I cannot understand why you think that you need mana in order to attack. Is there something that you haven't mentioned in the question that requires you to pay in order to attack? Please add an example with real cards.

Comment: re the close votes: "this question seems to involve a misunderstanding about the basic rules" is not the same as "unclear what you're asking". We can help beginners too, as shown by the two answers.

Comment: You may want to check [the Basic Rulebook (PDF)](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_PrintedRulebook_LR.pdf), as it would clear up some misconceptions you appear to have about the game. This is not the fold-out that may have come with your cards - this is a full rulebook that covers more grounds, and has helped me get a handle on the game as well.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to pay mana to attack unless a card specifically says so. So, if you take control of a black creature using a white deck, you can attack with that creature.

Answer (score 3):

The only cost-like requirement to attacking is the tapping of the attacker. There is no mana cost. While [certain cards](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22can%27t+attack+unless%22+or+o%3A%22can%27t+attack+you+unless%22&v=card&s=cname) impose restrictions on attacking, and while some even impose a cost (e.g. [Ghostly Prison](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghostly%20Prison)), the cost never requires colored mana.

Many creatures have abilities that require colored mana to activate. If you control such a creature, and if you don't have the ability to produce mana of that color, you may not activate its ability. For example, if you control a [Asphodel Wanderer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Asphodel%20Wanderer) and you have no means of creating black mana, you can't use its ability.

Comment: of course you also have Norn’s Annex which does ask for colored mana but that also can be paid with life

Comment: Could just as easily have said "of course you also have Norn’s Annex which asks for life, but can also be paid with colored mana"